# Unable to call function on click when injecting a component into leaflet marker (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, button, leaflet, angular-components

I am trying to click a button in a leaflet marker popup, in it I inject a separate component which is my marker popup content. For some reason I can't get any event to occur in the component, I can't call a function on click, it does nothing, no output or anything, I think it has something to do with the injection of the component but I can't seem to fix it.

volcano-map.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ComponentFactoryResolver, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import { environment } from '@env/environment';
import { mockVolcanoData } from '@env/mock-data';
import { VolcanoService } from 'src/app/services/volcano.service';
import { VolcanoPopupComponent } from 'src/app/components/volcano-popup/volcano-popup.component';

    //...... rest of the code ......

  private displayVolcanos(data: any) {
    data.forEach((volcano: any) => {
      const latitude = volcano.latitude;
      const longitude = volcano.longitude;
      const name = volcano.name;

      const marker = L.marker([latitude, longitude], { icon: this.markerIcon }).addTo(this.map);

      // Create an instance of VolcanoPopupComponent and pass the volcano data
      const componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(VolcanoPopupComponent);
      const component = componentFactory.create(this.injector);
      component.instance.volcano = volcano;
      component.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

      // Get the HTML content of the component
      const content = component.location.nativeElement.innerHTML;

      // Set the content of the popup
      marker.bindPopup(content, { minWidth: 450 });

      marker.on('popupopen', () => {
        marker.setIcon(this.defaultIcon);
      });

      marker.on('popupclose', () => {
        marker.setIcon(this.markerIcon);
      });
      

    });
  }
```

volcano-popup.component.html

```
<div style="display: flex;">

  <div>
    
    <div class="volcanoInfo">
      <h2 style="background-color: rgb(216, 229, 235); border-radius: 5px; padding: 3px;">{{ volcano.name }}</h2>
      <p style="font-size: medium; background-color: rgb(216, 229, 235); border-radius: 5px; padding: 3px;">Location: {{ volcano.location }}</p>
      <p style="font-size: medium; background-color: rgb(216, 229, 235); border-radius: 5px; padding: 3px;">Type: {{ volcano.type }}</p>  
    </div>

    <div style="width: 100%;">
      <h3>Add Volcano Activity</h3>
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Activity Name</label>
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newActivity.name" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>VEI</label>
          <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="newActivity.vei" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Activity Start</label>
          <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="newActivity.start" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Activity End</label>
          <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="newActivity.end" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }" required>
        </div>
        <button class="submitButton" type="button" (click)="addVolcanoActivity(newActivity)">Register Activity</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    
  </div>

  <div style="margin-left: 55px; background-color: rgb(216, 229, 235); width: 60%; border-radius: 5px;">
    <div>
      <h3 style="text-align: center;">All Volcano Activities</h3>
      <div style="height: 440px; width: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; margin-left: 5px;">
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let activity of volcano.activities">
            <b>Name: </b>{{ activity.name }}, 
            <br>
            <b>VEI: </b>{{ activity.VEI }},
            <br>
            <b>Start: </b>{{ activity.start }}, 
            <br>
            <b>End: </b>{{ activity.end }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>

</div>
```

volcano-popup.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { VolcanoService } from 'src/app/services/volcano.service';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-volcano-popup',
  templateUrl: './volcano-popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./volcano-popup.component.css']
})
export class VolcanoPopupComponent {
  @Input() volcano: any;
  newActivity: any = {}; // Object to store the new activity data
  isAddingActivity = false; // Flag to indicate if an activity is being added

  constructor(private volcanoService: VolcanoService) {}

  addVolcanoActivity(newActivity: any) {
    this.isAddingActivity = true; // Set the flag to indicate activity addition is in progress
    console.log(newActivity)
    this.volcanoService.addVolcanoActivity(newActivity)
      .pipe(finalize(() => this.isAddingActivity = false)) // Set the flag back to false on completion or error
      .subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
          // Activity added successfully, update the local data
          this.volcano.activities.push(response);
          this.newActivity = {}; // Clear the form inputs
        },
        error: (error) => {
          // Handle the error, e.g., display an error message
          console.log('Error adding volcano activity:', error);
        }
      });
  }

  getVolcanoActivities() {
    this.volcanoService.getVolcanoActivities(this.volcano.id)
      .subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
          // Activities retrieved successfully, update the local data
          this.volcano.activities = response;
        },
        error: (error) => {
          // Handle the error, e.g., display an error message
          console.log('Error retrieving volcano activities:', error);
        }
      });
  }
}
```